# Link from Beta SE back to proposal on Area 51?

Tags: feature-request, beta-phase

I'm participating in the [gadgets SE](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/) and wanted to refer to the on- and off-topic questions on the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614) proposal.  However, I couldn't find a link to it anywhere in the SE site.  If I'm not missing the obvious, could we have one?

Comment: There is such link, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235213/how-do-i-get-from-a-beta-site-to-its-area-51-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a feature that will probably become less and less useful, and eventually unnecessary, as time goes on, since the site will develop its own corpus of actual questions that will be a better guide to what's on-topic or off-topic. I personally would be fine just keeping the Area 51 proposal open in another tab or something, if it's needed, for the first few days. So I don't think this is really that important.

If it does get added, it should definitely be a feature of only the beta site interface, and should get removed at some point (possibly as early as when the private beta ends).

Comment: This was right after the Beta site opened, but I agree that it gets less useful as it moves to a full-fledged SE site.

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes, this is an oversight. I'll fix it in a more general way so it works for all sites.