# What happens to the top five on-topic and off-topic questions when a site goes live?

Tags: discussion, area-51, example-questions

I went to the new Web Applications site (now in beta), and I noticed that the top five on-topic example questions and off-topic questions were not mentioned at all in the FAQ.  I was quite surprised to see this.

If the top five on-topic and off-topic example questions (which are meant to define the scope of the site) are not included in the FAQ, then what's the point of creating them in the first place?

Comment: See Jeff's answer to a similar question I asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57161/link-from-beta-se-back-to-proposal-on-area-51/57182#57182

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should (or will) a proposed site's "Great On-Topic Example" questions be automatically included in its beta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55105/should-or-will-a-proposed-sites-great-on-topic-example-questions-be-automati)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is to have them for the topic definition phase -- if people can't agree on that there is nothing to "define" and nothing can proceed on the site proposal.

As to whether they are "perfect" or "ideal" questions to be written in concrete for all time, I am not so sure.

The actual behavior on the private beta trumps the definitions.