# After reaching the commit phase, can the definition be refined?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

After a proposal moves to the commit phase, is the functionality of the definition phase still available?

1. Can we still vote/unvote for example questions?
2. Can we still add, edit or delete example questions?

I'm asking mainly because I'm curious to know if we are stuck with the first 5 questions to be accepted or can we continue to refine the definition throughout the commit phase?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I take it there's no area51 meta? (There is a stackexchange meta, but I'm not sure whether that is better suited to area51 meta type questions.)

Comment: @JYelton: There's [Area51 Discussion](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/) which may or may not fulfill that function, depending on what you want to discuss.

Comment: Yeah, good point. There is a meta.stackexchange.com, which would seem like a better place, but the area51 FAQ links to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Actually, the 'meta' link in the header of StackExchange.com points to this site. I guess they're still working on it.

Comment: @JYelton and Kevin, this is where you ask questions about Area 51. Discussion is for questions about actual proposals, but if you want to know about the site itself you ask here. ♪

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition phase is locked when the proposal reaches the commitment phase.  Nothing can be changed in the definition phase after that.

However, once launched, the site can still evolve into something somewhat different from its original proposal.  This has been proven numerous times, the most notable example of which is [Programmers.SE.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Note that the on-topic and off-topic questions and answers are *not posted to the new site's FAQ* for this very reason.

Comment: Thanks Robert. How did you find that out? Is it on another posting somewhere or do you have insider information? Just want to make sure I've got a reference.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57593/what-happens-to-the-top-five-on-topic-and-off-topic-questions-when-a-site-goes-li and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55105/should-or-will-a-proposed-sites-great-on-topic-example-questions-be-automati