# How do I get from a beta site to its Area 51 page?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-sites, navigation

It's easy to click "Visit the site now!" on the Area 51 page, but how can I go back without using the search engine on Area 51 or using the back button on my browser?

Comment: and without using the back button on your browser, right? ;P

Comment: Yes.

Comment: Yes, but there's no actual answer about "Site stats" link there.

Comment: Furthermore, this is a support question, not a feature request like that one from four years ago (which may predate implementation of the link in my answer).

Comment: @NiallC. I agree with OP and with Nick, this is not a duplicate. Please retract your vote.

Comment: The vote will expire in a week anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When clicking on [`Visit the site now!`, e.g., for Hinduism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism/visit), the page you'll reach is https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/. You can also reach this page at any time by clicking the `Hinduism beta` link on the top left of all pages on the beta site, or manually by removing whatever follows this segment of the URL in your address bar. This page has a `Site Stats` box in the sidebar on the right, which features a link to the Area 51 proposal page under `more site stats on:`
[image]